# Preparing categorical and mixed data for KNN in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have written my own function to build a knn model.

It works well with numerical data.

My question is how to prepare categorical and mixed data for KNN in R?

I will provide two type of data I encountered.

1- [Mixed data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data)

Some rows and columns of the data

```
      V1                V2      V3            V4 V5                     V6
1     39         State-gov   77516     Bachelors 13          Never-married
2     50  Self-emp-not-inc   83311     Bachelors 13     Married-civ-spouse
3     38           Private  215646       HS-grad  9               Divorced
4     53           Private  234721          11th  7     Married-civ-spouse
5     28           Private  338409     Bachelors 13     Married-civ-spouse
6     37           Private  284582       Masters 14     Married-civ-spouse
7     49           Private  160187           9th  5  Married-spouse-absent
8     52  Self-emp-not-inc  209642       HS-grad  9     Married-civ-spouse
9     31           Private   45781       Masters 14          Never-married
10    42           Private  159449     Bachelors 13     Married-civ-spouse
11    37           Private  280464  Some-college 10     Married-civ-spouse
12    30         State-gov  141297     Bachelors 13     Married-civ-spouse
```

2- [Categorical data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data)

Some rows and columns of the data

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23
1     p  x  s  n  t  p  f  c  n   k   e   e   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   k   s   u
2     e  x  s  y  t  a  f  c  b   k   e   c   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   n   n   g
3     e  b  s  w  t  l  f  c  b   n   e   c   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   n   n   m
4     p  x  y  w  t  p  f  c  n   n   e   e   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   k   s   u
5     e  x  s  g  f  n  f  w  b   k   t   e   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   e   n   a   g
6     e  x  y  y  t  a  f  c  b   n   e   c   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   k   n   g
7     e  b  s  w  t  a  f  c  b   g   e   c   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   k   n   m
8     e  b  y  w  t  l  f  c  b   n   e   c   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   n   s   m
9     p  x  y  w  t  p  f  c  n   p   e   e   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   k   v   g
10    e  b  s  y  t  a  f  c  b   g   e   c   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   k   s   m
11    e  x  y  y  t  l  f  c  b   g   e   c   s   s   w   w   p   w   o   p   n   n   g
```

Comment: Confider using some encoders. For istance [CatEncoders](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CatEncoders/CatEncoders.pdf) package which provide `LabelEncoder` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example with one column. (`df` is your Mixed data)

```
library(CatEncoders)

test <- df$V4 # select one column

lenc <- LabelEncoder.fit(test)

print(lenc)
# An object of class "LabelEncoder.Factor"
# Slot "classes":
# [1] 11th         9th          Bachelors    HS-grad      Masters
# [6] Some-college
# Levels: 11th 9th Bachelors HS-grad Masters Some-college
#
# Slot "type":
# [1] "factor"
#
# Slot "mapping":
#        classes ind
# 1         11th   1
# 2          9th   2
# 3    Bachelors   3
# 4      HS-grad   4
# 5      Masters   5
# 6 Some-college   6

tranformed_test <- transform(lenc, test)
print(tranformed_test)
# [1] 3 3 4 1 3 5 2 4 5 3 6 3
```

**Update**

Use `sapply` function to transform all columns in dataframe

```
t <- function(x) {
    # check if x is numeric
    if(is.numeric(x)) {
        return (x)
    }
    l <- LabelEncoder.fit(x)
    y <- transform(l, x)
    return (y)
}

new_df <- sapply(df, t)
```

Comment: And for _categorical_ dataframe add if clause for checking if value is not numeric

Comment: KNN use Euclidian distance to distinct group. So when you have outliers or not it's always better to standardize your data

Comment: Yes, but you can write it simpler